# Does a constant power prop exist? What are the tradeoffs compared to a constant speed prop?

Tags: flight-controls, propeller, constant-speed-propeller

Variable-pitch props allow pilots to adjust the angle of attack of the propeller to change the load on the engine.

The most common implementation of this is a constant speed prop where the prop governor adjusts pitch to maintain the chosen RPM.

From a pilot's perspective, we only really care about two things:

- Power output
- Fuel economy

Using a constant speed prop, you can't directly set the output power - you set the throttle and prop speed and observe the power output.

Using a constant speed prop, you also can't directly set the fuel flow rate - you set the throttle and prop speed and observe the fuel flow (or look up the POH).

Using a constant power control law instead the pilot could set the desired power and have the prop pitch adjusted automatically to maintain that (or if impossible, fail in a similar way to a constant speed prop going off the governor).

It is also possible to pick the most fuel efficient RPM for a given engine load which means that the two inputs (throttle + prop speed) get reduced to one: desired power.

The benefits I see are:

- Reduced workload
- Increased efficiency

The drawbacks I see are:

- Inability to operate the engine at anything other than best efficiency **for a given power** - but I don't actually know what use case that would be useful in.
- System complexity
- Certification cost

Has a constant power control system ever been used in aviation? Are there other drawbacks that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you looking for an [ECU](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Full_Authority_Digital_Engine_Control_(FADEC)) whose input is directly translated in percentage of available power? or directly in a given power (let's say throttle full forward correspond to 200hp, midcourse to 125hp,...)?

Comment: In terms of (combustion) engine performance, rpm matters a lot. This surely partly explains why there are constant speed props. In fact, you generally design your engine to have a maximum power for take-off speed, then maximum efficiency for cruise speed. Also, some unstable phenomena forbid to stay in some areas of the operating range (especially for turboengines).

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are actually hoping to achieve.  For example, your comment that you cannot set fuel flow but can only observe it is incorrect.  You absolutely can set the fuel flow.  Every time you move the throttle the fuel flow changes.  If you want to set a specific fuel flow simply adjust power and prop to a setting that will achieve it.

Comment: @ManuH yes, but also factoring in available prop pitches to pick the most efficient way to produce 125hp etc

Comment: @MichaelHall Throttle does not set fuel flow (but does affect it) - this is obvious by the fact that changing the prop setting while keeping the throttle constant changes your fuel flow (ie. reducing RPM with a constant throttle will reduce the fuel flow)

Comment: @digitalPhonix, What is the difference between setting and affecting?  If you affect it then you can control it, and if you can control it you can set it.  Right?  And I actually said "If you want to set a specific fuel flow simply adjust power and prop to a setting that will achieve it."  So I understand prop affects it too.  The point is, fuel flow is just one performance metric, one that can be set with existing controls.  So again, I am not sure what you are asking, or what problem you are trying to resolve...

Comment: The prop lever directly controls the prop speed - once you set the prop speed no matter what you do with any other controls (withing the prop governor's ability) the prop speed will stay the same; you set the prop speed. This is not the same relationship between throttle and fuel consumption; you affect the fuel consumption by both prop speed and fuel consumption.

Comment: You affect the fuel consumption by prop speed and throttle (and mixture, altitude etc.)*

Comment: 2 points: Firstly, "From a pilot's perspective, we only really care about two things: power output [and] fuel economy." While fuel economy is an issue, what pilots want from the engine is to maintain the desired speed (vertically and horizontally), and the specific power value is of no interest (even when you need maximum power, you are not aiming for a specific value; you want the closest you can get to what would give the rate of climb and airspeed or acceleration that you would prefer in the situation.) ...

Comment: Secondly, no specifically _propeller_ control mechanism would have full authority over power. What you are asking for seems to be a single-lever engine management system that optimizes the propeller pitch automatically.

Comment: @sdenham A) no - as a pilot I care about more than speed; that's the whole reason I have the ability ways to achieve the same speed B) correct - in the same way the prop control doesn't have full authority over prop speed but does have the correct authority when operating within some envelope.

Comment: @digitalPhonix Of course we care about more than speed, but saying that is just a way to dodge the issue here, which is that power is not one of those other things we care about for its own sake.

Comment: @sdenham - ok, is your statement that prop RPM is something a pilot cares about for its own sake? I don't understand the point that you're making

Comment: @digitalPhonix You have a point, and I will even spot you this one: power (WRT the nominal max) is the parameter used for less-than-full-power takeoffs in transport aircraft. This does not help, however, in making the case for a specifically const-power propeller being a better alternative to a constant-speed one, particularly given the complications of implementing the former. Given an airplane with a CS prop, and RPM  and manifold pressure gauges,  is there any situation where you have to be frequently adjusting the engine controls _with the purpose of_ maintaining a constant power output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some aircraft that indeed have just power lever and set the RPM on schedule, e.g. the Pilatus PC-7, PC-9, PC-21 line of trainers. Since they are primarily designed for training future jet pilots, and jet aircraft only have power levers, it makes sense to skip the complexity of separate propeller and condition controls.

However normally there are some cases where you do want to set other than most efficient RPM for current power and true airspeed:

- The most common is descent and approach. These are flown with high RPM because

  - the engine is already spinning fast, so it does not have to spool up if you need to add power to go around and
  - with retarded power it produces more drag, allowing to expedite the descent when needed (the Pilatus PC-7/9/21 have a ventral speed brake; most turboprops don't).
- Failure modes, though for most a feather switch would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Do you know how those aircraft measure the shaft power and adjust throttle/pitch to maintain it?

Comment: And thanks for those two cases!

Comment: @digitalPhonix, I don't know, but I don't think they'd actually measure power, just have the power settings mapped to fuel flow and RPM (it is a turbine engine, so no mixture to fiddle with).

Answer (score 0):

A constant-speed prop lets the *pilot* select the speed setpoint for the prop/engine system with the *prop* control. With that control in the full-forward (fine pitch) position, full throttle applied to the engine will result in the engine revving up to its maximum rated RPM.

Then adding pitch to the prop so as to load down the engine (at full throttle) will cause it to slow down to any desired RPM setpoint. At that RPM setpoint, pulling back the throttle will cause the pitch to decrease as the governor system strives to maintain the RPM setpoint.

Working the throttle and the prop controls in this way lets the pilot select *any possible combination* of prop pitch and engine RPM desired. The operation manual contains charts that specify the power output of the engine for every possible combination of those parameters, and on those charts the "best power" and "best economy" combinations will be marked.

So, if the pilot has to execute a climb during cruise, they will select the "best power" combination of manifold pressure and RPM for that altitude by adjusting the throttle and prop controls necessary to produce it- and then monitor the resulting cylinder head and oil temps to make sure they don't go into the red. Once they arrive at the assigned altitude, then they will go back to the "best economy" setting for that (new) altitude.

Comment: Why would a pilot ever want any setting that isn't best economy for a given power setting? Eg. In a C177 I can produce ~125bhp @ 2000ft using: 2100rpm/24" (burning 9.0 gph), 2200rpm/23" (burning 8.9 gph), 2300rpm/22.5" (burning 8.7 gph), 2400rpm/22" (burning 9.0 gph) and 2500rpm/21.5" (burning 9.2 gph). Why would I ever pick anything other than 2300rpm/22.5" if I wanted to produce 125bhp?

Comment: And yes, I understand it allows you to select any possible operating point - I'm asking why are the inputs speed and throttle? Power and throttle would also allow you to pick any operating point; as would power and rpm. (The second part of the question was asking about dropping the second input, in which case you can't select any operating point)

Comment: there's no way to measure power directly; you need to put RPM and manifold pressure onto a chart from which you then read off the resulting horsepower.

Comment: @nielsnielsen, that most GA aircraft don't have a power indicator installed does not mean there is no way to measure it. Larger piston airliners usually had one (often labelled BMEP) and it was used as a reference to set mixture for best power. These days turboprops usually only have torque and RPM though.

Comment: I know in maritime applications too the shaft power is directly measured so the measurement part is a solved problem (maybe not within the weight/cost constraints of GA - in which case that would be the answer to my question).

Comment: Light planes can also adjust the mixture - this is often used to help with engine cooling too. I do that in my Cardinal as well.